# Update product price using a hook in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I am trying to update the product regular price using the meta key `_regular_price` with an integer or string when the product is updated in the wp-admin.

My desired user-flow is:

1. Open the product edit page
2. Click the update button
3. See that the _regular_price is set to 20 after the page has reloaded.

---

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'update_test' );
function update_test( $post_id ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', 20 );
}
```

Please help me find what I'm doing wrong in the above function and let me know of any other ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated** *(August 2018)*

Your code is correct but the hook is made for Metaboxes custom fields.

You should use instead [**`save_post_{$post->post_type}`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/) Wordpress hook **targeting product post type only**.

Also You may need to update the active price and **to refresh the product transient cache** with the function [`wc_delete_product_transients()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_delete_product_transients.html#135-181).

So your code will be:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_the_product_price', 10, 3 );
function update_the_product_price( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    if ( $post->post_type != 'product') return; // Only products
    
    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_product', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;

    $price = 50; // <===  <===  <===  <===  <===  <=== Set your price

    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id ); // The WC_Product object

    // if product is not on sale
    if( ! $product->is_on_sale() ){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', $price ); // Update active price
    }
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', $price ); // Update regular price
    wc_delete_product_transients( $post_id ); // Update product cache
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works…

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

To process woocommerce_process_product_meta, I guess you are missing the parameters. I hope the below code may suit your need.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta',  $wc_meta_box_product_data_save,  $int,  $int );
```

Parameters (3)

- $wc_meta_box_product_data_save (string) => 'WC_Meta_Box_Product_Data::save'
  The wc meta box product data save.
- $int (int) => 10 The int.
- $int (int) => 2  The int.

You can find the details [in this link](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_process_product_meta/).

Comment: I added `10, 2` as integers and it did not create the desired result.
Other things, like `_stock` and all my custom meta, update fine with my above function. It is only the `_regular_price` that causes the issue.