# Woocommerce Add to cart button for custom product

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have created a custom product with some custom fields in woocommerce. I dont see add to cart button for these custom products. I have updated my custom fields with `woocommerce_process_product_meta` but still I dont see add to cart button. What are the basic product fields I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Shall use `save_post` instead of `woocommerce_process_product_meta`. Also use `wc_delete_product_transients( $post_id )` at the end of hook . This is an helpful answer [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277671/update-product-price-using-a-hook-in-woocommerce)